# Membership in complexity classes

Tags: complexity-theory

I am struggling with a specific question regarding complexity classes. The question goes as follows:

There are three languages A,B,C so that:

1. A is NP-complete
2. B is in P
3. C is polynomial time reducible to A $\triangle$ B (symmetric difference)

Which of the following statements is valid:

1. C is in P
2. C is in NP
3. C is in coNP
4. C is in NP $\cap$ coNP

I was able to determine that C is in NP due to the polynomial time reducibility but am unsure about the other statements.

Comment: Hint: What happens if $B = \emptyset$? What happens if $B = \Sigma^*$? In both cases, you can simply assume that $C = A \Delta B$ – the polytime reduction makes no difference here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, do I understand correctly that none of the statements is correct?

Comment: It depends on the relations between P, NP and coNP.